# RMAN Recovery In Oracle 11g : Backup Database To Tape

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rman

On issuing this command:

```
RMAN> backup device type sbt tablespace <tablespace_name>;
```

we are getting the following error:

```
ORA-19554: error allocating device, device type: SBT_TAPE, device name: 
ORA-27211: Failed to load Media Management Library
```

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Have you configured the tape accordingly? Edit your post with the output of `show device type;`.

Comment: RMAN> show device type;            

            RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name ORCL are:
         CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
         CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default

Comment: Ok, so it hasn't been configured. What make/model of tape device is it, how is it presented to the host, and do you have the external library/software rman needs for it (if one is indeed available/needed)?

Comment: How to check make/model of tape device?

Comment: Ask your sysadmin...

Comment: Given your database is called ORCL, is this actually a production system with a tape drive/backup system in place or is it a hobbyist question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "device" in RMAN is a misnomer, it should be really called "storage".

The "sbt" (synonym of "sbt_tape") is a misnomer again, as it has NOTHING to do with any tapes, it should be simply called "non-rman". This is just an empty placeholder, to be filled with any "plugin"; the plugin is called by Oracle either the "Media Manager library" or SBT_LIBRARY. This plugin allows rman to store and retrieve files through it, so rman only tells that it needs a file handle "xyz" (file is identified by a string handle) and doesn't need to know how the file is delivered, from tape or anything. The plugin is normally a part of an independent backup software, such as IBM TSM or Symantec NetBackup or many others. Oracle provides a simple emulator SBT_LIBRARY=oracle.disksbt for testing.

Since you didn't fill that placeholder with any "Media Manager library", you receive an error message as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a Tape Device for your backup tasks, then you might be using disks? 
Either way, try assigning a device/path to the SBT device before you perform your backup:

Start RMAN from your prompt

```
rman ENTER
```

Connect to your target

```
RMAN> connect target /
```

Allocate a path you your SBT device (this is for a path device):

```
RMAN> allocate channel for maintenance device type sbt parms 'SBT_LIBRARY=oracle.disksbt, ENV=(BACKUP_DIR=<your backup directory>)';
```

Issue your backup command without the SBT device:

```
RMAN> backup tablespace <tablespace_name>;
```

I once read:

> You should configure default devices and channels in advance of running RMAN Backup.
>   [RMAN Backup | SS64.com](http://ss64.com/ora/rman_backup.html)

Good luck!